# How can I add a module to the tags page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, tags

I created a site with Joomla3.

When I click on the tags link on a blog post, it shows a page of articles but without a module.

I want to add a module to this page.

Comment: Please describe in greater detail what you are trying to accomplish.  Complete tutorials tend to be Too Broad and attract vague/generalised/incomplete answers. You question can invite high value answers if you edit your question to include the research that you have done and what you have tried so far to self-solve.

Answer (score 1):

The display of modules on a Joomla website is generally controlled via the "Menu Assignment" tab when editing the module in Module Manager.

Clicking on a tag link may take you to a different page so that modules displayed on the original page are no longer displayed on the new page.

Module assignment options are:

- On all pages
- No pages
- Only on the pages selected
- On all pages except those selected

You might be able to solve your issue if you change the module assignment option to "On all pages" or "On all pages except those selected" with an appropriate selection.